# How to delete object Redis list item?

Tags: javascript, express, caching, redis

I am using delete function in a scenario for cache deleting data from mongodb but[image] how can i delete data which is specific object from redis. I used Lrem() but it didn't work, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
const deleteComment = async (req, res) => {
  let key = `Comments/${req.query.postId}`;

  try {
    const deleteValue = await Comment.findOneAndDelete({
      _id: req.params.id,
      $or: [{ writer: req.user.id }, { authorId: req.user.id }],
    })
      .populate("responseTo", "writer")
      .populate("postId", "authorId")
      .populate("writer");

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(deleteValue);
    await client.lRem(key, 0, jsonData);

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ success: true, message: "Comment Deleted", ıtem: deleteValue });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is jsonData stringifying to match the data in Redis exactly? If it doesn't, it won't be removed.

Comment: @GuyRoyse I think it doesn't match, so what should I do to make it match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the code that inserts the JSON? If so, you'll need to make sure they generate the same strings. [LREM](https://redis.io/commands/lrem/) requires an *exact* match to work. That said, you might want to consider a different data structure or maybe a combination of data structures.

One option is that you could store the JSON as a [String](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string) and then the [List](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list) could contain the keys to those [String](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string)s. Then, when you delete a comment, you call [LREM](https://redis.io/commands/lrem/) to remove it from the [List](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list) and [UNLINK](https://redis.io/commands/unlink/) or [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del/) to remove the JSON. The [List](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list) serves to store an ordered index of the comments. The comments themselves are each stored in a [String](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string).

If you can use [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/), you could just store a JSON document with an array of the comments. That would give you ordered data and the data itself and then you could delete a particular comment using [JSON.DEL](https://redis.io/commands/json.del/) and JSONPath.

Comment: I solved the problem according to what you said, thanks